# Makefile dependency without declaring a rule?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a pattern rule that converts a type definition in a typescript file to a JSON schema file. The program that does this conversion requires two parameters:

- The name of the `source file`
- The `typename` to be extracted from that file

I have decided to encode the required typename as the name of the target file.

```
<--------- Typename --------->        <------- source file ------->
BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json : block-language.description.ts
```

And I defined this pattern rule to do the conversion:

```
%.json : %.ts
    # $^ is the name of the input file
    # $(notdir $(basename $@)) is the filename of the target file (without the .json suffix)
    $(TYPESCRIPT_JSON_SCHEMA_BIN) --path $^ --type $(notdir $(basename $@)) > "$@.json"
```

Sadly the `<typename>.json: <sourcefile>` rule I setup as a dependency is a more specific rule compared to the pattern rule and therefore **the pattern rule is never executed**. So I decided to wrap the conversion in a `define CONVERT_COMMAND` and simply use this in every single of the above definitions:

```
BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json : block-language.description.ts
    $(CONVERT_COMMAND)
```

While this does work, the repetition strikes me as ugly. Is there a way to declare a dependency from one file to another while still preferring the pattern rule?

**Minimal repro**: Run this with `make BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json Unrelated.json` and observe that the `echo` is never executed.

```
block-language.description.ts :
    touch $@

another.description.ts :
    touch $@

%.json : %.ts
    echo "generic target"

BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json : block-language.description.ts
Unrelated.json : another.description.ts
```

If this helps: The debug output is as follows.

```
❯❯❯ make --debug=verbose BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json                                                                                          
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
Reading makefile 'Makefile.json' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile '../../Makefile.common' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Updating makefiles....
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json'.
  Considering target file 'block-language.description.ts'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'block-language.description.ts'.
  No need to remake target 'block-language.description.ts'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json'.
 Prerequisite 'block-language.description.ts' is newer than target 'BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json'.
Must remake target 'BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json'.
Successfully remade target file 'BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json'.
make: 'BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json' is up to date.
```

Comment: I do not understand. How many rules (pattern or not) do you have with `BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json` as a target? And if you have more than one, why is it so? Note: in your pattern rule's recipe you should probably redirect to `"$@"` instead of `"$@.json"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer this without seeing a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I think I see the problem. This pattern rule:

```
%.json : %.ts
    ...whatever...
```

uses `foo.ts` to build `foo.json`. Make will not attempt to use it to build `BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json`, because there is no `BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.ts`.

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
%.json :
    @echo do various things with $@ and $^

BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json : block-language.description.ts
```

Note that the second rule has no recipe, it simply provides the prerequisite.

Comment: I added a minimal complete example for futures sake and I am stumped: I was under the impression I could only use `$^` if the pattern rule itself had a defined dependency. But this just works, thanks alot!

Comment: No, automatic variables are always available and you can add prerequisites as many different times as you want.  Only one rule can have a _recipe_ though.  Note, `$^` is the wrong automatic variable, most likely.  You want `$<` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the mapping from dependency to target name is well defined you could script that part, send the output into a makefile -- say `deps.mk` -- and include that in your main makefile.

It appears the name mapping is something like...

```
<text-with-dashes>.description.ts --> <Capitalized text without dashes>.GeneratorDocument.json
```

The following perl script reads each `.ts` file name from its arg list and generates a suitable dependency...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# -*- perl -*-

use strict;

while (defined(my $file = shift(@ARGV))) {
    my($d) = ($file =~ m,^(.*)\.description\.ts,);
    my @d = split("-",$d);
    s/(.)/\u\L$1/ for @d;
    $d = join("",@d);
    print "\nall: $d"."GeneratorDocument.json\n$d"."GeneratorDocument.json: $file\n\t\$(CONVERT_COMMAND)\n";
}
```

If we name the above script `mapname.pl` then...

```
./mapname.pl block-language.description.ts
```

should give the output...

```
all: BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json
BlockLanguageGeneratorDocument.json: block-language.description.ts
        $(CONVERT_COMMAND)
```

Now your main makefile would be...

```
ALL_TS_FILES := $(wildcard *.description.ts)
MAPNAME      := ./mapname.pl

all:

include deps.mk

deps.mk: $(ALL_TS_FILES) $(MAPNAME)
    $(MAPNAME) $(ALL_TS_FILES) > $@.tmp
    diff -q $@ $@.tmp || mv $@.tmp $@
```

Comment: Sadly the mapping is not that straightforward, there may be multiple typenames that are generated out a singular file.

Comment: I added a minimal complete example that illustrates this problem.